# Disk encryption without cooperation from system

Tags: encryption, usb-flash-drive, embedded

I have a small embedded system that supports fat32. It does not have any encryption options for the files that it saves to a external usb connected disk. Modifying the source to support encryption is not an option. Are there any external drives, or somethings that can be used to encrypted the files once the land on the disk? Something that does not require the cooperation of the embedded system?

I realize that this is a bit far fetched, but you never know!

Comment: What's the use scenario? Do you have to read from the device on the embedded system as well as write to it? I'm thinking you have a key management problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a few options which allow you to disarm the encryption until the next power cycle.

https://superuser.com/questions/296750/independent-hardware-based-encryption-tool-used-with-non-cooperative-system-and

Answer (score 1):

The [IronKey](https://www.ironkey.com/personal) USB devices have on-device encryption.  A Google search for [encrypted hard drive](http://www.google.com/search?q=encrypted+hard+drive) yields some useful looking results.

Comment: It looks like this one requires a software install on the system.

Comment: Hmm, I missed that.  Some of the other devices looked completely self-contained.